# minitoc overwrites headings in KOMA-Script

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, minitoc

When I use the `minitoc` package with the `scrreprt` class of KOMA-Script, the `\parttoc` command modifies the headings set with the `scrlayer-scrpage` package `\automark` command. Is there a way to prevent this?

To reproduce this behavior, run the code below as is, and un-commenting the `\parttoc` line.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage,minitoc,lipsum}
\automark{part}

\begin{document}
    \doparttoc
    \part{p1}
    \parttoc
    \chapter{c1}\lipsum
\end{document}
```

You can see below the headings of the second page of text.

- with `parttoc`:

[image: with \parttoc]

- without `parttoc`:

[image: without \parttoc]

Comment: Sorry, but I see no difference with and without `\parttoc`. Maybe I'm blind. But it would help, if you show, where you get the difference. BTW: There is a warning about using `minitoc` with KOMA-Script class in the log. So maybe this is a XY-problem. And please also note the `\thispageparttocstyle` in the `minitoc` manual. But I don't know, whether or not it is relevant for your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I could have been more clear with that. I have added a couple of screenshots to show the difference. I've seen the warning, but the manual doesn't really specify what the issues could be. Also, I'll take a look at `\thispageparttocstyle`. Thanks!

Comment: I have the result of the second screenshot also with `\parttoc`. But its page 3 not page 2 of the example document (maybe this is, what you meant with “second page of text”, but I'm not sure). Are you using up-to-date versions of [KOMA-Script](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) and [`minitoc`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minitoc)?

Comment: You're right, that's the reason why I said 2nd page of text (that is the page after the chapter page). I do have up to date versions of both.

Comment: Please add `\listfiles` to your document and show the file list from the end of the log file and also the lines from `This is …` (first line) down to `L3 programming layer …`